# C char array printing, using subroutine

Tags: c, arrays, char, subroutine

There is code using c:

```
const char *bits[] = {"0000","0001","0010"};
```

When I call printf-function it works fine:

```
prinft("%s",bits[1]); // this prints correct value
```

But when I try call subroutine function it stops program:

```
print(*bits);
void print(const char *bits)
prinft("%s",bits[1]); // system stops working
```

How can I print a correct value?

Comment: See the type of argument .

Comment: First of all, please try to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then for your problem, look at the formal argument for your `print` function, and then think about what `bits[x]` means inside the function.

Comment: "prinft"? Won't compile.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `print(*bits)` you give `bits[0]` as the argument, which is `char*`. Then you tell `printf` to output a string (which is `char*` in C) and you give it `bits[1]` which is actually of type `char`, specifically the second `char` in the `bits`. `printf` will treat this value as `char*` and this will naturally cause a problem.

Comment: @Olaf Badly worded and not needed, so removed that part. Thanks for the comment. Was meant if I had suggested sending `char**` for which the `bits` could've been given directly.

Answer (score 1):

At first, I am a Chinese Student.So maybe my English writting is not good.

I think there are some mistakes in your code.
you should understand pointer(example: int *ptr or int ptr[]) and the pointer points to a pointer(example: int **ptr or int *ptr[]).In your codes, bits is a pointer points to a pointer, because you used * and [] meanwhile.
So, if you want to transfer bits to the print() Function, you should use

```
void print(const char **bits){
    printf("%s\n", bits[0]);
}
```

or you can write print() as below:

```
void print(const char *bits){
    printf("%s\n", bits);
}

//in main()
print(bits[0]);
```

it depends what you what print() to do.

ps:This is my first answer on Stack Overflow. if you find some Grammar mistake with English, please tell me.Thx.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for comments. The solution was here. Need to remember this **pointer / *pointer (depent of situation).